# How to get column name and column lable when given query have inner query in left join

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Can anybody help me to get actual column name and its alias using `ResultSetMetaData`

```
    class MysqlCon {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "root");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT \n" + 
                    "  RA_Min_1 AS 'ran Min',\n" + 
                    "  RA_Max_1 AS 'ran Max' \n" + 
                    "FROM\n" + 
                    "  `Masters` m \n" + 
                    "  LEFT JOIN \n" + 
                    "    (SELECT \n" + 
                    "      mr.`Master_ID`,\n" + 
                    "      `RA_Min_1`,\n" + 
                    "      `RA_Max_1` \n" + 
                    "    FROM\n" + 
                    "      `Master_Attribute_Range` mr \n" + 
                    "      INNER JOIN `Masters` m \n" + 
                    "        ON m.`Master_Type_ID` = 3 \n" + 
                    "        AND mr.`Master_ID` = m.`Master_ID`)  mar\n" + 
                    "    ON mar.Master_ID = m.`Master_ID` \n" + 
                    "    AND m.`Master_Type_ID` = 3 \n" + 
                    "ORDER BY RA_min_1 \n" + 
                    "LIMIT 0, 25 ";

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            ResultSetMetaData rsm =rs.getMetaData();
            for (int i = 1; i <= rsm.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println(rsm.getColumnLabel(i) + "--" + rsm.getColumnName(i));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output

```
ran Min--ran Min
ran Max--ran Max
```

Here, if i remove `ORDER BY RA_min_1` clause then it will return expected output:

```
ran Min--RA_Min_1
ran Max--RA_Max_1
```

**UPDATE**

First of all Sorry, as I am unable to reply as I had some personal issues, and due to those issues I am not able look stack over flow. please forgive me for that. Thanks.

*Normal query without sub query will give result as expected. but I have a situation where i have to use sub queries and need both alias and actual field name.*

To put question here, I have truncated sub query with only one field, but in real scenario, sub query after LEFT JOIN is very big and contains many columns like `RA_Min_1, RA_Max_1,RA_Min_2, RA_Max_2,...RA_Min_50, RA_Max_50 and some other columns`.

We are preparing dynamic query in which some time we have `RA_Min_1, RA_Max_1` and sometime `RA_Min_2, RA_Max_2`.

So, here I am looking for solution with sub query.

Any help will be Appreciated!!

Thanks.

Comment: It is entirely possible that this information is lost in certain transformations.

Comment: Just in case... What if, in the query, you use the (standard) backticks to define the column names instead of single quotes, like: `RA_Min_1 AS \`ran Min\``?

Comment: have you tried ordering by the lable? like ORDER BY `ran Min`

Comment: But what is `ResultSetMetaData`?  Maybe we need to see its definition.

Comment: Please provide the entire `SELECT` statement without the quotes and plusses needed for building the Java string.

Comment: Which "actual column name" do you need, and why?

Comment: @GMB, result is same with or without (standard) backticks

Answer (score 1):

This query should give you the same result as yours:

```
SELECT
    RA_Min_1 AS 'ran Min',
    RA_Max_1 AS 'ran Max'
FROM `Masters` m
LEFT JOIN `Master_Attribute_Range` mr ON m.`Master_Type_ID` = 3 AND mr.`Master_ID` = m.`Master_ID`
ORDER BY RA_min_1
LIMIT 0, 25;
```

Does it fix your label prblem?

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the full query as multiline text.

```sql
SELECT 
  RA_Min_1 AS 'ran Min',
  RA_Max_1 AS 'ran Max' 
FROM
  `Masters` m 
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
      mr.`Master_ID`,
      `RA_Min_1`,
      `RA_Max_1` 
    FROM
      `Master_Attribute_Range` mr 
      INNER JOIN `Masters` m 
        ON m.`Master_Type_ID` = 3 
        AND mr.`Master_ID` = m.`Master_ID`)  mar
    ON mar.Master_ID = m.`Master_ID` 
    AND m.`Master_Type_ID` = 3 
ORDER BY RA_min_1 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

The selected list of fields are ambiguous. The subquery aliased as `mar` has `RA_Min_1` and `RA_Max_1` fields so that when this is joined with `masters` table, the available fields will be `m.RA_Min_1`, `m.RA_Max_1`, `mar.RA_Min_1`, `mar.RA_Max_1`.

If fields from the subquery are selected either explicitly or implicitly. For example

```
SELECT 
  mar.RA_Min_1 AS 'ran Min',
  mar.RA_Max_1 AS 'ran Max' 
-- ...
ORDER BY mar.RA_min_1
LIMIT 0, 25
```

**Output**

```
ran Min--ran Min
ran Max--ran Max
```

Then the result set loses information about column name in the result set metadata.

In order to keep the original column name, selected fields should be from the table when it is possible.

```
SELECT 
  m.RA_Min_1 AS 'ran Min',
  m.RA_Max_1 AS 'ran Max' 
-- ...
ORDER BY m.RA_min_1
LIMIT 0, 25;
```

**Output**

```
ran Min--RA_Min_1
ran Max--RA_Max_1
```

The query can be refactored as the sub-select query is joining on the same table in the select query.

`SELECT 
  m.RA_Min_1 AS 'ran Min',
  m.RA_Max_1 AS 'ran Max' 
FROM
  Masters m
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
    mr.Master_ID, 
    RA_Min_1, 
    RA_Max_1 
    FROM 
      Master_Attribute_Range mr 
      INNER JOIN Masters m 
        ON m.Master_Type_ID = 3 
        AND mr.Master_ID = m.Master_ID )  mar
    ON mar.Master_ID = m.Master_ID
    AND m.Master_Type_ID = 3 
ORDER BY m.RA_min_1 
LIMIT 0, 25`

which is

```
SELECT 
  m.RA_Min_1 AS 'ran Min',
  m.RA_Max_1 AS 'ran Max' 
FROM
  Masters AS m
  LEFT JOIN   
  Master_Attribute_Range AS mr 
  ON m.Master_Type_ID = 3 
  AND mr.Master_ID = m.Master_ID
ORDER BY m.RA_min_1
LIMIT 0, 25
```

Answer (score 0):

Darshan, try creating an index on the RA_min_1 column and see if that helps.

Comment: In the absence of index, MySQL could use temp table to hold the output of the outer select for ordering and at that point the original column name might be getting lost.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that could work.  Use only the column name in you existing query's top level `select` and pipe it to another `outer select` where you select using the label.

An example to demonstrate this:

```
mysql> select col_x as label_col_x from table order by col_x;
```

becomes

```
mysql> select col_x as label_col_x from (select col_x from table order by col_x) as label_table;
```

In the above, `label_table` is label for the inner select output and is required by MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

the inner join clause  is useless, you could only Left join  and it give you exactly the output needed :

```
SELECT
    RA_Min_1 AS 'ran Min',
    RA_Max_1 AS 'ran Max'
FROM Masters m
LEFT JOIN Master_Attribute_Range mr ON m.Master_Type_ID = 3 AND mr.Master_ID = m.Master_ID
ORDER BY RA_min_1
LIMIT 0, 25;
```

**INNER JOIN** gets all records that are common between both tables based on the supplied ON clause.

**LEFT JOIN** gets all records from the LEFT linked table  and  the common columns from the RIGHT table.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting table aliases as the columns are ambiguous. Maybe MySQL is confuse where to get the reference.

In pgsql, I tried but no luck.